# 500 Internal Server Error by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have files in `htm` that contain php code and i can run these files by htaccess code. I have done nothing but now suddenly when i am trying to open that page i got `500 Internal Server Error` i just remove all the code from htaccess file now it showing all my code in text form.

this is htaccess code

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .php .html
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

why i am getting `500 Internal Server Error` when i open my web page but if i just remove this code file code displayed as text.

Please point me in right direction what is wrong with this code

Comment: can you check your error log and say what error is mentied

Comment: Is the php valid? what does the error log say? what happens if you just put `<?php phpinfo();` in an file and try to load that?

Comment: there is no error_log file generated

Comment: You've somewhere given an unexpected condition, try editing it line by line to debug what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @user3262732 **no error log** you run your program in `localhost` or `hosted server` if local host whats your server wamp or xamp

Comment: @user3262732 check the server's error log as well.

Comment: i am running on hosted server

Comment: `<?php phpinfo();` i place this code into an htm file it still give me `500 internal server error`

Comment: i request you to run i local server can you

Comment: not possible to run this on localhost

Comment: `!=` is not proper. it should be just `!on`. modrewrite regexes have no "equals". And check your server's error log. It'll tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: i think this is not a syntax error because `<?php phpinfo();` page is also giving same error

Comment: @user3262732 then its littel hard to solve hire some expert

Comment: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .php .html
IndexIgnore *` just using this code but still getting same error

Comment: Rename this .htaccess and see if 500 goes away.

Comment: by just renaming the `htaccess` file `500 internal server error gone`

Comment: but now how can i run htm files

Comment: Did you try without `IndexIgnore *` ?

Comment: yes i also test without this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are using PHP as Apache module. In that case have just this one line in root .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

`AddHandler` is required when you run PHP as CGI.